# Viewing all applications in an alphabetical list in 4.4.2

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat

On Android 4.1.2 I was able to view all applications in an alphabetical list:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to do so in Android 4.4.2? By default applications are in a grid:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.